Exception when trying to subscribe to Kafka topic before it is created
I'm trying to subscribe to a wildcard topic like "^my-topic-name-*". At the time of subscribing, these topics do not exist yet. The result is the following exception:
   Confluent.Kafka.ConsumeException: Subscribed topic not available: ^my-topic-name-*: Broker: Unknown topic or partition
      at Confluent.Kafka.Consumer`2.Consume(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
      at Confluent.Kafka.Consumer`2.Consume(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Note the the exception only happens when I actually try to consume:
var consumeResult = _kafkaConsumer.Consume(stoppingToken);

Unfortunately, I cannot find if this is expected behavior or if I'm doing something wrong. In short, how can I subscribe to and consume from wildcard topics before they're created?
